# child of element this jquery

Tags: jquery, input, this

I want do sth like this:

```
$(".game-cover").mouseenter(function() {
    $($(this)+" :input").css("background-color", "#A2D205");
});
```

But I don't know how combine elemnt **this** with **:input**. Could somebody help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`jQuery.find`](http://api.jQuery.com/find) to find the descendants which also accepts a selector, in your case `:input`

```
$(".game-cover").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(":input").css("background-color", "#A2D205");
});
```